# WordPress: Plugin Development - multiple wp_enqueue_scripts in two or more plugins

Tags: wordpress

I got a problem with wp_enqueue_scripts during plugin development. I built two different plugins and both of them have wp_enqueue_scripts to add CSS files in a head section. The problem occurred when I activated both of my plugins. This adds CSS only from the first activated plugin and ignores the second one. Can you please tell me what should I do to avoid this problem. Here is the code:

First Plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_general_css' );

function add_general_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('css/general-css.css', __FILE__) );
}
```

Second Plugin:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );

function add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('css/shortcodes.css', __FILE__) );
}
?>
```

Thank you,
Art

Answer (score 3):

Unique handles are required, e.g. `prefix-style-01` and `prefix-style-02`